AJAX Request Failing with 500 Internal Server Error
I’m trying to send an AJAX request to my server using jQuery, but I keep getting a 500 Internal Server Error response. Here’s the code I’m using:
$.ajax({  
    url: "/api/update-user",  
    type: "POST",  
    data: JSON.stringify({  
        userId: 123,  
        status: "active"  
    }),  
    contentType: "application/json",  
    success: function(response) {  
        console.log("Success:", response);  
    },  
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {  
        console.error("Error:", status, error);  
    }  
});  


Details:
The endpoint /api/update-user is a custom route on my server.
When I test the endpoint with tools like Postman, it works fine and returns the expected response.
The server is running on Node.js, and I’ve confirmed that the route and handler are correctly defined.
Debugging Steps I’ve Taken:
Checked the server logs, and the error seems to occur when parsing the JSON body of the request.
Verified that the Content-Type header is set correctly to application/json.
Tested with different payloads to ensure the problem isn’t with the data.
Questions:
Could this issue be related to how AJAX sends the request versus Postman?
Is there something in my server-side code (e.g., middleware for body parsing) that could cause this inconsistency?
Are there any debugging tips to narrow down why this works in Postman but fails with AJAX?
Any insights would be greatly appreciated!
